# Requesting undeletion of old roomba'd question that I'd like to answer and make visible

Tags: support, deleted-questions

https://serverfault.com/questions/841780/fragmentation-leads-to-excessive-vhdx-backup-size
Took me nearly 2 years to figure it out by myself, way too long for SF. Since it's a wtf-worthy curiosity and I happened to get reminded of it while going through my old notes, I figured it wouldn't hurt to try to revive it and finally add some semblance of an answer to it. Could a mod help me out with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem to revive it as it seem on-topic. Thanks for taking the time to add an answer to the question.